# Entity Framework with Waterfall or Agile?

Tags: entity-framework, agile, waterfall

I've seen plenty of posts on the pros and cons of the EF but finding quite hard to find anything on the relationship between EF and project management methodologies such as Waterfall SDLC and Agile?

Would anyone have any links or information on the above? Thanks.

Comment: discussions of pros and cons of a particular process are generally subjective, and are difficult to provide a single, definitive answer for.  That, coupled with the request for off site resources, makes this site not a good fit for this inquiry.

Comment: @Claies - Even pure programming question on this board have a healthy chunk of subjectivity to them, particularly when assessing which solution is "the best". That's why there are voting buttons; to bring collective judgment to bear on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frameworks and methodologies are typically orthogonal.

The only (indirect) relationship is that Agile methods would have you build your application to be decoupled from the persistence mechanism altogether. In fact, you would delay even using a database until you have a user story that requires that you have one. This would force you to keep the two decoupled, leaving your options open.